# How to reference a Class Library (.xproj) in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a 3-tier sample app (PL, BLL, DAL). Now I created BAL and DLL as separate xproj. I want to reference (if this is the correct term for ASP.NET 5) the DAL xproj to BLL xproj. What I tried is adding it to the BLL's project.json as an entry like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "MyDal": "1.0.0"
 }
```

But this says cannot resolve. Also, how do I know (or set) the version of the xproj that I create? I looked in the property pages but I can't find it there.

Comment: Did you try to reference via Visual Studio 2015, it should automatically update the project.json. Otherwise you can change the output directory of your class libraries to a common folder and add this folder as nuget source

Comment: You can try the 'dnu restore' command. You will need to set the path in the command window to the root of the BAL project and then execute the 'dnu restore' command.